# How can i get the unselected items from dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can i get the unselected items from dropdown using jQuery

Comment: (-1) Please explain in more detail what you mean. You have a track record of asking unintelligible questions - please start working on this, and consider listening to the suggestions already made to you.

Comment: Useful resource: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$('select#xyz option:not(:selected)');
```

or

```
$('#mySelect option').not(':selected');
```

Comment: `"select#xyz"` as a selector is actually slower than `"#xyz"`. The latter looks into `document.getElementbyId()`, which is easily the fastest way of selecting.

Comment: @James is correct...also I can't think of an instance where this would be an efficient way to solve the problem :)

Comment: I wanted to show clearly that I was selecting a select.

Comment: @Nick: efficient way to select unselected options in a dropdown? or are you referring to why select them in the first place as the questioner asked? if the former, then what's efficient?

Comment: Both :) `$("#xyz").val() != "something"` would typically be how to go about this, `#xyz` instead of `select#xyz` and `[selected]` would be the most efficient, but my point was more of selecting the options in the first place, a bad approach by the OP I imagine, but maybe there's some wacky valid reason for this I can't imagine....