# How to Get Non Selected index from the Dropdown List?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two items in the Dropdown list and i have the code for getting Selected Item.But now i want to Get the Non Selected index from the Dropdown List. Here is the code for getting selected Value : `$("select[name='SelectInning'] option:selected").index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this , it may works `$("select[name='SelectInning'] option:not(:selected)")`

It works: check out this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jzinedine/6zsDs/2/)

Comment: Correct direction, working code is: `$("select[name='SelectInning']").not("option:selected")` [live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9PK5/) (your code give -1)

Comment: @MoizKachwala see my comment and test case for working code. The `not` filter is the correct way indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for multiple options to get index

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658672/how-can-i-get-the-unselected-items-from-dropdown-using-jquery)

On top of that you can use .index() function to achieve your output.

Comment: Thanks Akash for your Reply.. Really Greatful.. I guess that would be helpful for me..